# Woocommerce Rest api product filters not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to integrate the woocommerce rest apis with my app. All the defaults operations like create/update product, get all products, get products by category etc are working perfectly fine. However filtering product results based on some chosen filters are not working. For example if I want to filter products with color=Red and brand=Arrow then the api doesn't work.

Can someone please let me know how are product filters supposed to be implemented.

I am trying to pass the filters in the below manner:

/wc-api/v3/products?filter[category]=accessories&filter[brand]=KOOVS - This doesn't seem to be working, getting the same result set regardless of what filters I set. Only category filter works.

Comment: Hey @Madhan, Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Should be like this**

accessories&filter[brand]="KOOVS"

**not**

accessories&filter[brand]=KOOVS

**since its a string**